# Store html content generated with PHP into a variable

Tags: php, html, wordpress, variables, store

I have some PHP code mixed with HTML and i need to store this  into a variable but i can't figure out how can i do that. When this code is executed, is called from a shortcode that calls the function and works perfectly.The PHP code render the HTML and shows the information from the DB, but now i need to store the result `(this html divs boxes with information from the database)` into a variable in order to send this variable to a function in wordpress that can update a page. When i try it, there is a error that say echo isnt spected. I know that this variable doesn't spect php code inside, so how can i do that? store the result into a variable?

any suggestion will be very apreciated
thank you in advance:

```
$ultimosProyectosHome+="
echo '<div class="cont-proyectos">';
echo '<div style="text-align:center;"><a href="'. $url_actual .'"?      page_id="'. $id_paginaFicha .'" target="_blank">';if($pregunta6Valor!=""){echo '<img src="http://www.xxx.xx/xxx/xxx/'.$pregunta6Valor.'" alt="Cover"></a></div>';} else{echo '<img src="'.$imgDesafio.'" alt="Cover"></a></div>';}
                            echo '<h3>';if($pregunta2Valor != ""){ echo $pregunta2Valor;}else{echo $Nodefinido;}echo'</h3>';

                             echo'<a href="'. $url_actual .'"?page_id="'. $id_paginaFicha .'" target="_blank">';
                                    echo'<h4>';if($pregunta1Valor != ""){ echo $pregunta1Valor;}else{echo $Nodefinido;} echo'</h4>';
                                echo'</a>';                                    
                                echo'<p>'; if($pregunta3Valor != ""){ echo getSubString($pregunta3Valor,198,$id_paginaFicha);}else{echo $Nodefinido;} echo'</p>'; 

                                echo'<div class="redesSocialesTLP" id="redes">';
                                    echo'<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url="'. $url_client .'"?page_id="'. $id_paginaFicha .'"&text="'. $pregunta1Valor .'" target="_blank">';

                                        echo'<i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i>';
                                    echo'</a>';


                                    echo'<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="'. $url_client .'"?page_id="'. $id_paginaFicha .'" target="_blank">';

                                        echo'<i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i>';
                                    echo'</a>';

                                    echo'<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url="'. $url_client .'"?page_id="'. $id_paginaFicha .'" target="_blank">';

                                        echo'<i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-2x"></i>';
                                    echo'</a>';
                                echo'</div>';
                            echo'</div>';
```

";

Comment: Create one variable string with all the information you have above without all the echos. Then just echo the whole string or pass it to whatever.

Comment: Thank you Jose. your answer is like Iserni correct way. I use ob_start(); for now and works. Eventually, I have to create a variable string with all the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

Your code may benefit from the answer below but you're doing a different, and more dangerous, thing. You've a blob of HTML and PHP and want to *execute* it to store its results. To do this, you need something like [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). Or equivalently, you can write the code to a temporary PHP file with unguessable name, then re-include it in your script while wrapping it in output buffering.

I've seen it done using a "sandbox" server with limited rights, but that's complicated to implement.

The danger depends on where your code comes from. If someone else can modify it, then he will be able to execute arbitrary code on your server, which you definitely want to avoid.

For this reason some *templating languages* have been developed - you may 
want to look into [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/), for example.

Otherwise, you can now do:

```
$bunch = "<BUNCH OF MIXED CODE FROM ABOVE>";

ob_start();
try {
     eval($bunch);
} catch (\Exception $err) {
     print "There has been an error.";
}
$ultimosProyectosHome += ob_get_clean();
```

### Back to "storing mixed output into variables"

**The correct way**:

```
 $html = '';
 ...
 // Remove all occurrences of this
 echo "Something";
 // and this
 echo "<br />";
 // and write it like this instead.
 $html .= 'Something';
 $html .= '<br />';
```

This can become awkward if you have functions that produce output. You'll have to rewrite them to return the output (just like above, end with

```
 return $html;
```

and then wherever you had

```
 callToFunction(parameters);
```

you'll refactor with

```
 echo callToFunction(parameters);
```

Then, further refactor it to read

```
 $html .= callToFunction(parameters)
```

iteratively.

**The lazy way**

Using [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php). A great way to hog memory, lose control of your script, and play merry hell whenever you'll want to debug it (unless you go with Xdebug, but then why do the lazy thing in the first place?).

```
 ob_start();
 ...
 $html = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: I need to use the lazy way at the momment. Only for testing. I have to do it in the correct way eventually. This is what i needed.Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is output buffering.

Call `ob_start();` before echo'ing your content, then at the end:

```
$content = ob_get_clean();
```

Everything that was output between those two functions will then be stored in `$content`.

There's further information on these functions - and other options as well - in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php).

Keep in mind output buffering should generally be a last resort - don't get too comfortable with doing this everywhere!

By the way, you can avoid all the calls to `echo` by just ending the PHP block (`?>` and starting it again when you're done (`<?php`).

Comment: Thank you very much Tim, this was usefull.

Comment: Amazing, must Know for every PHP Developer out there!